# Adding a build dependency in iOS

Tags: xcode, ios, dependencies

How is a build dependency added to an iphone application?

If a .xcodeproj is added to an application, how is it added as a build dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. right-click ( or ctrl-click ) on the appropriate target ( under Targets )
2. go to the General tab
3. Click on the plus button under "Direct Dependencies"
4. Select your desired target to make a dependency, and hit add target

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+click on the app's target, click Properties and go to the first tab. Then, add a dependency and select the xcodeproj's target which you'd like as dependency.